# Use groupby and find ratio

Tags: python, pandas

Input:

```
  Boro Completed?
0    M          Y
1    M          Y
2    Q          N
3    Q          Y
4    Q          Y
```

Desired output:

```
  Boro Completed?  Ratio
0    M          Y    1
1    M          Y    1
2    Q          N    0.67
3    Q          Y    0.67
4    Q          Y    0.67
```

As you can see, the M boro is totally complete, Q is not. I want to show the ratio of completion by boro.

Currently I only have the overall rate of completion, unable to figure out how to use groupby for this.

```
data = {'Boro':['M','M','Q','Q','Q'],
       'Completed?':['Y','Y','N','Y','Y']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Ratio'] = df[df['Completed?'] == 'Y'].shape[0]/df.shape[0]
```

Comment: I think this makes no sense, why `1,1` but not `0.333, 0.666,0.666`?

Comment: should it be 0.67?

Comment: Yes, my error, it should be .67

Answer (score 0):

We do `transform`

```
s=df['Completed?'].ne('N').groupby(df['Boro']).transform('mean')
Out[66]: 
0    1.000000
1    1.000000
2    0.666667
3    0.666667
4    0.666667
Name: Completed?, dtype: float64
df['ratio']=s
```